# Azure Devops - New service connection - ACR - No registries found

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-registry

I am the Co-Administrator (Owner) of the Azure subscription. When i try to create new service connection in the azure devops to the Azure continer resitry, I am reciving following error
"No registries found"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Issue resolved. Some unknown issue from azure. My colleague created repository now he is no longer with us. I could not able to see that repository eventhough i have all permissions in azure and azure devops.

I did trail and error.

Disabling and re enabling Admin user in ACR fixed the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue where my registry wasn't listed (no employee who had left though). Unbelievably, this worked for me too. Many thanks

Comment: And here we are in Feb 2023 and it still needs to be done

Comment: and March 2023 :)

Comment: I did that (enable and re-disable admin user in ACR) but nothing really happened (at least instantaneously). Next day I checked again and registry was visible and elegible.

Comment: September 2023, one year on, and this still hasn't been fixed. On rare occasions a popup appears, though that hasn't happened for a long time now. Very poor MS!